# How to extend the contractor base class (sqlite3.Database)? nodejs, ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make my extended version of `sqlite3.Database` and I want to do it in the ES6 way ,as simple and readable as possible.
That is my solution:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
class DBExtend extends sqlite3.Database {
    constructor(file) {
        super(file);
        this.foo = function() {
            return 4;
        }
    }
    test() {
        return 4;
    }
}

var t = new DBExtend("test.db"); //creates an object of DataBase
console.log(t.foo()); // OK
console.log(t.test()); // TypeError: t.test is not a function
```

As is clear, the above syntax fails to add methods to the child class.
My question is:
  - Why it don't work?
  - What if I add methods in constructor and after call to `super()` using `this.foo = function() {}` syntax?

Comment: What is `sqlite3.Database`? Is it class or constructor function?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski , so what is the right way to extend constructor style classes?

Comment: The code itself seems fine to me. I look at the `sqlite3.Database` code and it uses C modules for the actual database instantiation. The way it uses it may impact whether it can be extended or not. As an example of what I mean: `class X { constructor() { return new Z(); }} ; class Y extends X { foo() { return 42; }}`. I would never be able to do `var y = new Y(); y.foo()`, because constructing `X` actually returns a new `Z` instance, not a `X` or `Y` instance.

Comment: Factory functions (or factory-like constructors) cannot be extended with `class`, as they don't respect `new.target`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with JavaScript prototypal inheritance and ES6 classes.

There are few differences:

- class can be only extended by another class
- there is no **super** keyword

Classes are only sugar for prototypal inheritance, extending prototype always works in the almost the same way.

```js
'use strict'

function Parent(arg) {
  this.arg = arg
}

Parent.prototype.parent = function() {
  return this.arg.toUpperCase();
}

Parent.prototype.child = function() {
  return 'Access to original method'
}

class Child {
  constructor(arg) {
    this._super_.constructor.call(this, arg)
  }
  parent() {
    return 'Result of acccess to parent method: ' + this._super_.parent.call(this)
  }
  child() {
    return "Access to overloaded method"
  }
}

function extend(parent, child) {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(parent.prototype, child.prototype)
  child.prototype._super_ = parent.prototype
}

extend(Parent, Child)

let b = new Child('initial value')
console.log(b.child())
console.log(b._super_.child())
console.log(b.parent())
```

Comment: IMO, if the original es6 method declaration way do not work for the case , using `this.bar = function (){}` after `super()` in the child constructor looks better.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question? What exactly are you trying to demonstrate with this answer?

Comment: @FelixKling - answer shows how to access to new created method or method from parent class / function.

Comment: But that's not the OP's question. The question is why they cannot call `t.test()` (which only returns 4).

Comment: @FelixKling - extend doesn't work with function as constructor, it works only with other ES6 classes. Please read comment like "so what is the right way to extend constructor style classes" - made 2 hours ago by Reza Afzalan - Than my answer shows how to do it or not?

Comment: *"extend doesn't work with function as constructor, it works only with other ES6 classes."*. That's not correct. Here is a clone of your example using `extends` and `super`: https://jsfiddle.net/t4z32f69/ . You are saying yourself that `class` is just syntatic sugar for constructor functions. Whether you used `class` to create that function or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @FelixKling - nice job, please add answer to the question